# iOS not updating label text

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, touchxml

I'm parsing xml here and am wondering why this is not working. In my request object, I do this

```
- (Request *)performRequest{
NSError *error;
CXMLDocument *parser = [[CXMLDocument alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=%3CTrackRequest%20USERID=%22827ACSTU1155%22%3E%3CTrackID%20ID=%22EJ958088694US%22%3E%3C/TrackID%3E%3C/TrackRequest%3E"] options:0 error:&error];
if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"An error has occured. Try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
NSArray *arr = [parser nodesForXPath:@"//TrackResponse/TrackInfo/TrackSummary" error:nil];
self.keyVal = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", keyVal);

return self;
}
```

the nslog is showing

```
<CXMLElement 0x2005c7c0 [0x2005cfb0] TrackSummary <TrackSummary>Your item was delivered at 1:39 pm on June 1 in WOBURN MA 01815.</TrackSummary>>
```

which I expect. However, in my view controller, I do this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
Request *re = [[Request alloc]init];
[re performRequest];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI:) withObject:re waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)updateUI:(Request *)re{
self.info1.text = re.keyVal;
NSLog(@"%@", re.keyVal);
}
```

however, the label (info1) and the log show (null). Why is this?

Comment: Can you put the same NSLog(@"%@", re.keyVal); right before the performRequest:?  Let's see if we can see the data at that point.  My guess is that it will be null, and there's a problem with the keyVal ivar or getter.

Comment: yea, well it turned out in my .h I had `(weak, nonatomic)` for the keyVal, so that caused it to be released before I could use it. I fixed it using `(retain, nonatomic)`

Comment: This is a string, it should be `copy`, not retain. If it's a non-mutable string this will be optimized to just `retain` anyway, but it's good matters to always copy strings, arrays and dictionaries. Also, you should answer your own question and mark it as solved. ;)

Comment: okay, so all fixed then?  if so can you write an answer and mark it correct, or I will if you'd prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this on my own by declaring the property in the header as

```
(nonatomic, retain)
```